# How to make sure to get error_logger reports with line numbers on process crashes

Tags: logging, error-handling, erlang

If I spawn a process using *spawn_link* BIF, i seem to automatically get a useful error report when the spawned process crashes, clearly indicating exactly at which line of code the crash occurred. However, if I instead spawn the process using *proc_lib:start_link* I do not get that useful information.

**QUESTION:** How can I make sure that I get the detailed error report upon crashes, as shown below, regardless of how the process was spawned?

Example to illustrate this:

```
-module(crasher).
-export([start1/0, start2/0, init1/0, init2/0]).

start1() ->
        proc_lib:start_link(?MODULE, init1, []).

start2() ->
        spawn_link(?MODULE, init2, []).

init1() ->
        proc_lib:init_ack(ok),
        crash().

init2() ->
        crash().

crash() ->
        crash = here.
```

Which results in this behaviour:

```
42> crasher:start1().
** exception exit: {badmatch,here}
43> 
43> 
43> 
43> crasher:start2().
** exception exit: {badmatch,here}
     in function  crasher:crash/0 (crasher.erl, line 18)
44> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Mar-2016::11:51:57 ===
Error in process <0.244.0> with exit value:
{{badmatch,here},[{crasher,crash,0,[{file,"crasher.erl"},{line,18}]}]}

44>
```

Note that when *proc_lib:start_link* was used, I get only a *badmatch* atom, but when *spawn_link* was used, I get a neat error report stating exactly at which line the crash happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure you always get useful error reports and save yourself a lot of debugging time, run the [SASL (System Application Support Libraries) application](http://erlang.org/doc/man/sasl_app.html). With `sasl` running, you get a full crash report from the `crasher:start1/0` call:

```
1> application:start(sasl).

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 14-Mar-2016::09:05:24 ===
          supervisor: {local,sasl_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.59.0>},
<...long output abbreviated...>
ok
2> crasher:start1().

=CRASH REPORT==== 14-Mar-2016::09:05:31 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: crasher:init1/0
    pid: <0.64.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception error: no match of right hand side value here
      in function  crasher:crash/0 (/private/tmp/crasher.erl, line 18)
    ancestors: [<0.50.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.50.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 376
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 91
  neighbours:
    neighbour: [{pid,<0.50.0>},
                  {registered_name,[]},
                  {initial_call,{erlang,apply,2}},
                  {current_function,{proc_lib,sync_wait,2}},
                  {ancestors,[]},
                  {messages,[{ack,<0.64.0>,ok}]},
                  {links,[<0.26.0>,<0.64.0>]},
                  {dictionary,[]},
                  {trap_exit,false},
                  {status,runnable},
                  {heap_size,2586},
                  {stack_size,27},
                  {reductions,4275}]
** exception exit: {badmatch,here}
3> crasher:start2().

=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Mar-2016::09:10:26 ===
Error in process <0.67.0> with exit value:
{{badmatch,here},
 [{crasher,crash,0,[{file,"/private/tmp/crasher.erl"},{line,18}]}]}
** exception exit: {badmatch,here}
     in function  crasher:crash/0 (/private/tmp/crasher.erl, line 18)
```

If you always want to start your interactive shells with `sasl` running, run `erl -boot start_sasl` from the command line.